# How to "reuse" the original Symfony ErrorListener to log exceptions in the same way Symfony does?

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony default [`ErrorListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ErrorListener.php) will log an uncaught exception, taking into the account the [`WithErrorLevel`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/attributes.html#httpkernel) attribute, the status codes and will pretty print the error with a lot of information.

In my controller, I call actions that may throw:

1. If I recognize the exception (based on a common interface), I'll show a custom error message to the user
2. If I do not recognize the exception, I want to call the `ErrorListener` **to log the exception for me**

Any idea on how to log the exception using `ErrorListerner` subscriber?

Comment: I'd just override default ErrorListener on the DI level and extend it to log only those exceptions you actually need to log.

Comment: @ozahorulia thanks for the input. I've got a clue looking at this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Fragment/InlineFragmentRenderer.php#L80

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

readonly class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onKernelException',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $throwable = $event->getThrowable();
        
        if ($throwable instanceof \InvalidArgumentException) {
            $event->setResponse(...);
        }
    }
}
```